# AS3 AIR Application - getItemAt Not working tracing item in DataGrid

Tags: actionscript-3, debugging, actionscript, air

Hi is this function non existant in AIR or somthing because I was trying the following trace as a test and it throw a fat error in my face,

```
trace(musicLibrary.getItemAt(3)[0]);
```

Musiclibrary is the datagrid I was just using the row number and column number as a test but is there somthing wrong with that?

```
TypeError: Error #1006: getItemAt is not a function
```

I don't understand because I haven't been able to find anywhere where it says this is not a valid function on the web. Anyone know?

Edit: Added what I ended up using.

Just to let anyone else know I ended up using this:

```
var songName:String = libraryDP.getItemAt(currentSongNumber+1).Song;
```

I was trying to get the vale of an object in a dataprodiver the data was added to an array like this.

```
musicLibrary.push({Song:arr[i].name,Location:arr[i].nativePath});
```

hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Datagrids do not have the getItemAt method defined. You can call that method on the datagrid's data provider however, like so: `musicLibrary.dataProvider.getItemAt(3)`.

Hope this helps.
Have a great day.

Comment: ... oh f**k me I just spent like 4 hours trying to fix that thanks man